# How can I access values in a hashmap that is in a different class

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to access values of a hashmap which is in a different class but I am not too sure how to.

The class 'employee' will never be instantiated. The goal is to have a single hashmap that belongs to the employee class in which I can put values into from the child classes, but only have the one hashmap shared between all objects of the child classes and objects. The HR class will be able to add worker objects to this hashmap. This is my code at the moment:

```
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Worker ben = new Worker(101, "Ben");
        HR HR = new HR(102, "HR");
        employeeList.get(101);
    }
}



abstract class Employee {

    HashMap<Integer, Employee> employeeList = new HashMap();

}


public class Worker extends Employee {

    int id;
    String name;

    Worker(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        employeeList.put(id, this);
    }
}


public class HR {

    int id;
    String name;

    HR(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        employeeList.put(id, this);
    }

    public static void createWorker(int id, String name) {
        Worker worker = new Worker(id, name);
        employeeList.put(id, worker);
    }

}
```

I am getting an error on the last line of my main method:

```
employeeList.get(101);
```

How do I resolve this so I can use this hashmap from anywhere in my programme?

Comment: Does it make sense for an employee to have a list of employees? It doesn't seem that your map belongs on that class.

Comment: The map is just going to be a list of employees, I will eventually have different child classes and it will be a collection of every instance of someone who works there

Comment: If you really want to keep a list of employees in the Employee class, you should look up what a `static` member is

Comment: I could have a parent class and put the map on the ‘office’ parent class but that would solve nothing, I’m just trying to figure out how to access the map from other classes

Comment: Then, apart from the `static` keyword, if you want your child classes to be able to modify a parent class' member, I advise you look up `protected` access

Comment: How would I change it through a class which has no relation to the class though? That’s my issue

Comment: First you should figure out _why_ you think that the map should be there in the first place. Typically, either the calling context should be owning the map, in which case there's no "other class" to worry about, or there should be some kind of dedicated directory object, in which case the appropriate way to set it up will depend on some specifics.

Comment: With the `protected` access keyword, you would be able to change it from child classes. Of course, that doesn't include your `HR` class, so either make `HR` extend `Employee` or set a `public` method to add elements to the map. However, as you're already being advised, that would complicate things too much, so consider another approach.